# C# AccessViolationException with interop callbacks in .NET 4.5 or above

Tags: java, c#, c++, interop

I'm investigating screen reader technology in C# and experiencing an issue regarding the capturing of events using an interop library written in C++ (Java Access Bridge - https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/tree/05a764f4ffb8030d6b768f2d362c388e5aabd92d/src/jdk.accessibility/windows/native/libwindowsaccessbridge) when compiled using .NET 4.5+ (64-bit). It crashes in both Debug and Release build configurations. **The functionality works fine in .NET 4.0 however**.

Whenever an event occurs that should trigger the registered callback, an AccessViolationException occurs, crashing the application. I suspect it has something to do with the Garbage Collector changes introduced in .NET 4.5 but would appreciate assistance in being able to track down the exact issue.

There is a complete minimal reproducible code project located here that subscribes to a mouseclick event -> https://github.com/needmoreraminbrainnow/screenreadertest.
When this is compiled with .NET 4.5 it will crash when a mouseclick event occurs within a Java-based application

The delegate is created as a class variable to maintain a reference. The two important methods on the C# side are...

```
[DllImport(WINDOWS_ACCESS_BRIDGE, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern void setMouseClickedFP(MouseClickedDelegate fp);

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate void MouseClickedDelegate(System.Int64 vmID, IntPtr jevent, IntPtr ac);
```

I believe the relevant C++ methods are...

```
void fireMouseClicked(long vmID, JOBJECT64 event, JOBJECT64 source);
```

and...

```
void AccessBridgeEventHandler::method(long vmID, JOBJECT64 event, JOBJECT64 source) { \
    DEBUG_CODE(char debugBuf[255]); \
    DEBUG_CODE(sprintf(debugBuf, fireEventDebugString, #method, event, source, vmID)); \
    DEBUG_CODE(AppendToCallInfo(debugBuf)); \
    if (eventFP != (FPprototype) 0) { \
        eventFP(vmID, event, source); \
    } else { \
        DEBUG_CODE(AppendToCallInfo("[ERROR]: eventFP == 0")); \
    } \
}
```

All I can find that corresponds to setMouseClicked is in C code here...

```
void SetMouseClicked(AccessBridge_MouseClickedFP fp) {
    if (theAccessBridgeInitializedFlag == TRUE) {
        theAccessBridge.SetMouseClicked(fp);
    }
}
```

and also...

```
#define CALL_SET_EVENT_FP(function, callbackFP)         \
    void WinAccessBridge::function(callbackFP fp) { \
            eventHandler->function(fp, this);                       \
            /* eventHandler calls back to winAccessBridgeDLL to set eventMask */    \
    }

CALL_SET_EVENT_FP(setMouseClickedFP, AccessBridge_MouseClickedFP)
```

I've tried pinning the delegate using `GCHandle.Alloc(_mouseClickDelegate, GCHandleType.Pinned);` but when run this results in a `Object contains non-primitive or non-blittable data` error. And based on research of similar questions and Microsoft articles it appears this should not be necessary.

I've tried using `GC.KeepAlive` for the delegate

I have also tried changes related to Marshalling of the delegate when setting the callback and using a different calling convention but to no avail.

I have also tried using the following struct as the callback argument type instead of IntPtr...

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public class JOBJECT64
    {
        public static JOBJECT64 Zero = default(JOBJECT64);

        private readonly long _value;

        public JOBJECT64(long value)
        {
            _value = value;
        }

        public long Value
        {
            get { return _value; }
        }

        public static bool operator ==(JOBJECT64 x, JOBJECT64 y)
        {
            return x._value == y._value;
        }

        public static bool operator !=(JOBJECT64 x, JOBJECT64 y)
        {
            return x._value == y._value;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj is JOBJECT64)
            {
                return this == (JOBJECT64) obj;
            }

            return false;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return _value.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

How can I confirm that it is a problem with the delegate being moved or inaccessible?

Comment: Please post actual code, not links to code. In the event, what is the **C definition** of the two P/Invoke functions and of the callback? And are you compiling your app under 32 bit or 64-bit architecture

Comment: thanks @Charlieface, I've added what I believe to be the relevant definitions from the C++ side along with the accompanying C# methods along with what I have tried so far. Also, this is when compiled as 64-bit

Comment: `setMouseClickedFP` where is that defined? What about `Windows_run` which is in your linked code? And it appears from a quick look at the docs that you need to call `initializeAccessBridge` and `shutdownAccessBridge`?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that Windows_run and initializeAccessBridge are called and work fine as per linked code as this all works fine when targeting .NET 4.0. I tried to keep the question targeted to the callback as it was downvoted with that additional information in

Comment: @Charlieface I've added what I can find from the underlying library regarding the corresponding methods and also a link to the library. As I say it appears to be something specific to .NET 4.5 and above as it all works fine in .NET 4.0

Comment: Debug and Release both crash. Have tried not optimising code also. Adding in the `GC.KeepAlive` to a `FormClosing` handler doesn't help either

Comment: Sorry, not thinking. In `JavaAccessBridge.HandleMouseClick` put in an extra line `GC.KeepAlive(_mouseClickDelegate);`

Comment: Adding this does not help either unfortunately

Comment: Have you tried the `GCHandle.Alloc(_mouseClickDelegate);` overload? Seems to work in code I have, however this is structured a bit differently, so cannot be copied just 1:1.

Comment: Thanks @PMF, yes I have tried that as per the details in the question.

Comment: You didn't specify whether you tried all overloads of `GCHandle.Alloc()`. The second argument could be related to that `Object contains non-primitive or non-blittable data` message.

Comment: Thanks @PMF. I can confirm that all overloads of `GCHandle.Alloc()` fail with the `AccessViolationException`

Answer (score 0):

there were some breaking changes in [.NET 4.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/runtime/4.0-4.5). if 4.0 works for you, then use it. after it's compiled and shipped out, it shouldn't matter much.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not going to be feasible as we want to make use of many .NET 4.5+ features.